# Insertar datos en dos tablas Mysql a partir de otra tabla

Tags: mysql, mysqli, mysqldb

Hola buen día compañeros. Actualmente estoy migrando mi data para mejorar mi pequeño sistema.

El asunto es que no se como Insertar en dos tablas, mi idea es que al insertar en la tabla "articulo" también se inserte en la tabla "ean" el campo ean y el id que sé insertó en la tabla "articulo".

Mi logica era con un ejemplo como este que encontré:

```
 INSERT INTO users(email,fbid) VALUES('randomvalue','otherrandomvalue') OUTPUT Inserted.id
```

**Tabla articulo original:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Tablas como deseo que termine mi data:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Probando mi idea inicial con INSERT INTO Y OUTPUT SELECT y algunas más que encontré en la red no me funcionaron. Espero sus comentarios. Muchas gracias comunidad :D

Comment: Quieres insertar datos de una tabla origen en las dos tablas destino dentro del proceso de migración de tus datos? Si es así, no es claro cómo estás intentando usar ese ejemplo en tu caso y con tus datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que necesitas es partir una tabla en otras dos.
Puedes hacer dos INSERTS con los valores seleccionados sacados de la tabla antigua

```
INSERT INTO Tabla_Final_EAN (ean, art_id) 
SELECT DISTINCT ean, art_id FROM Tabla_original

INSERT INTO Tabla_Final_Articulo (art_id, descripcion) 
SELECT DISTINCT art_id, descripcion FROM Tabla_original
```

Comment: No quedará de otra, tendré que hacerlo así